# Select only unique rows

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have this table:

```
  term
---------
park
park
apple
lamp
lamp
park
lamp
orange
orange
banana
orange
```

And I want to get all unique rows, so my query should return this:

```
apple
banana
```

How can I do it? All examples I find uses DISTINCT but that is not what I need.

Comment: why just `apple, banana`? why it shouldn't return `park, lamp, orange` ? why DISTINCT is not good for you?

Comment: @Alex because park, lamp and orange appear more than once. OP is looking for items that appear exactly 1 time.

Comment: "And I want to get all unique rows". It's in the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Using the term *unique rows* is too easily confused with *unique values* for which DISTINCT is used. That confusion is happening right now. You want the items that occur only once.

Comment: @Cornwell you are lucky this time. some people have understood your need. But it is really not so clear from your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `term`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `term`
HAVING COUNT(`term`) = 1
```